# IOS - NSMutableString: appending, and initializing a property

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I'm obviously not getting something with this.

I'm parsing an XML Document so I have an NSMutableString to append to for one of the elements because foundCharacters gets cut off and does it in pieces.  I can get this all working but I don't understand why doing it in a certain way it does not work.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableString *currentFoundCharacter;
```

This is how I declare the property for the ViewController.

Then I have:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {
    if (!currentFoundCharacter) {
      currentFoundCharacter = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // Have to do this or new strings never append to it.
    }
    if ([currentAttribute compare:@"description"] == NSOrderedSame && currentAttribute.length > 1) {
    [currentFoundCharacter appendString:[string copy]];
  }
```

Now this right here works.  It will combine within a element all that I want.  but if I try to use the synthesized methods I get error about mutating an immutable object so basically replace all currentFoundCharacters with self.currentFoundCharacters.

Maybe I misunderstood when and why to use the properties vs instance variables but outside of init methods and such I was under the impression it was better to use the setter / getters. In the end I just want to make sure I make maintainable code.

Comment: I wouldn't declare a mutable class as copy.

Comment: I also just learnt how to parse xml a few days ago.  There are only two differences I can see.  1. I did not make my 'currentFoundCharacter' a property of my class.  I only declared it in the interface.  2. I only allocate the NSMutableString once, and use `[NSMutableString string]` to empty it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use retain instead of copy in your property. Copy gives you an immutable copy.

Comment: CodaFi's comment above was right, I never put much thought into it, but I always just made NSString's copies so that they would own the string being passed in, without realizing that an NSMutableString would be different.  That solved my problem, but this answer technically was right as well.